# CollorAdjust with SwingX's ImageView?

Tags: java, image-processing, netbeans, javafx, swingx

I have a question about adjusting contrast, saturation and hue of an image that's loaded to jXImageView from swingx library.

I have the ColorAdjust methods.

```
ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
colorAdjust.setContrast(0.3);
colorAdjust.setHue(-0.03);
colorAdjust.setBrightness(0.2);
colorAdjust.setSaturation(0.2);
```

When the user click on the "Enhancement" button, the image should change a bit, but how to do that? Remember: I'm using the jXImageView.

I've increased the contrast already by using this code:

```
    float brightenFactor = 1.5f;
    BufferedImage imagem = (BufferedImage) jXImageView2.getImage();
    RescaleOp op = new RescaleOp(brightenFactor, 0, null);
    imagem = op.filter(imagem, imagem);
    jXImageView2.updateUI();
```

## Edit

I tryied:

```
BufferedImage imagem = (BufferedImage) jXImageView2.getImage();
Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(imagem, null);//<--ERROR on that line (incompatible types: writable image cannot be converted to Image)
ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
colorAdjust.setContrast(0.3);
colorAdjust.setHue(-0.03);
colorAdjust.setBrightness(0.2);
colorAdjust.setSaturation(0.2);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);//<--ERROR on taht line no suitable constructor for ImageView(java.awt.Image)
imageView.setFitWidth(imagem.getWidth());
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
imagem = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(imageView.snapshot(null, null), null);
jXImageView2.setImage(imagem);
```

...but without successful.

Comment: While you can convert `BufferedImage` to and from an `Image`, I don't know if the `ImageView` will apply the `ColorAdjust` values directly to the underlying `Image` or if it just uses them to change the way it is painted.  You could start by taking a look at [`SwingFXUtils`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html) for how to convert between the two image formats

Comment: Ahh, try [this](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2870355)!

Comment: *"<--ERROR on that line (incompatible types: writable image cannot be converted to Image)"* Did you use `java.awt.Image` or `javafx.scene.image.Image`?

Comment: Now I've tryied with the `javafx.scene.image.Image`

Comment: It show an error when I click on the Button:
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0`

Seems to be on this line: `imagem = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(imageView.snapshot(null, null), null);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample solution**

- Image on the left is the original image.
- Image on the right is the adjusted image (which has had the color desaturated to make the image monochrome).

[image: adjustedcolors]

This solution works by:

1. Converting the Swing/AWT [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) into a JavaFX [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html).
2. Using the JavaFX [ColorAdjust](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/ColorAdjust.html) effect to modify the image.
3. A [snapshot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) of the color adjusted image is taken to create a new JavaFX image.
4. The new JavaFX image is [converted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html) back to a new Swing/AWT BufferedImage.

Because the solution mixes two different toolkits, the following considerations were applied when creating it:

1. Be careful of imports used to ensure that the correct class is being used for a given toolkit call; e.g., both JavaFX and Swing/AWT have `Color` and `Image` classes, so it is necessary to ensure that the fully qualified class for a given toolkit is used in the right context - passing a Swing Image directly to a JavaFX API would be wrong and vice-versa.
2. Be careful of threading rules.  Snapshots of JavaFX scenes must be made on the JavaFX application thread.  Execution of Swing APIs must be made on the Swing event dispatch thread.  Various utilities of the respective toolkits (e.g., [`SwingUtilities`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) and the JavaFX [`Platform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html) class) are used to ensure threading constraints of the given toolkits are satisfied.
3. The JavaFX toolkit must be initialized before it can be used.  Normally this is done implicitly when your application extends the JavaFX [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) class.  However Swing applications do not extend the JavaFX application class.  So, perhaps somewhat counter-intuitively and poorly documented, a [`JFXPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) must be instantiated to initialize the JavaFX toolkit before the toolkit is used.

**Notes**

1. This solution is crafted to fit the particular requirements of the question (which is a Swing application which needs to make some color adjustments).  If you only wish to adjust image colors from within JavaFX and not use Swing, then [more straight-forward solutions](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2870355) exist and are preferred.
2. Calling `System.exit` is generally enough to shut the JavaFX toolkit down.  The sample application calls `Platform.exit` to explicitly shut the JavaFX toolkit down, but in this case the explicit call to `Platform.exit` is probably unnecessary.

This means that the ColorAdjuster in the solution can be used from a Swing program without the Swing program explicitly importing any JavaFX classes (although, internally, the ColorAdjuster will import those classes and the system must meet the normal minimum requirements to run both the Swing and JavaFX toolkits).  Reducing mixing of imports to a single toolkit per class where possible is desirable because mixing imports within a single class for a mixed JavaFX/Swing application is a good source of tedious errors, due to potential name clashes and threading related headaches.

*ColorAdjuster.java*

Image color adjusting utility.

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.effect.ColorAdjust;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

/** Uses JavaFX to adjust the color of an AWT/Swing BufferedImage */
public class ColorAdjuster {
    // Instantiation of a JFXPanel is necessary otherwise the JavaFX toolkit is not initialized.
    // The JFXPanel doesn't actually need to be used, instantiating it in the constructor is enough to trigger toolkit initialization.
    private final JFXPanel fxPanel;

    public ColorAdjuster() {
        // perhaps this check is not necessary, but I feel a bit more comfortable if it is there.
        if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "A ColorAdjuster must be created on the Swing Event Dispatch thread.  " +
                            "Current thread is " + Thread.currentThread()
            );
        }

        fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    }

    /** 
     * Color adjustments to the buffered image are performed with parameters in the range -1.0 to 1.0
     * 
     * @return a new BufferedImage which has colors adjusted from the original image.
     **/
    public BufferedImage adjustColor(
            BufferedImage originalImage,
            double hue,
            double saturation,
            double brightness,
            double contrast
    ) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        // This task will be executed on the JavaFX thread.
        FutureTask<BufferedImage> conversionTask = new FutureTask<>(() -> {
            // create a JavaFX color adjust effect.
            final ColorAdjust monochrome = new ColorAdjust(0, -1, 0, 0);

            // convert the input buffered image to a JavaFX image and load it into a JavaFX ImageView.
            final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(
                    SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(
                            originalImage, null
                    )
            );

            // apply the color adjustment.
            imageView.setEffect(monochrome);

            // snapshot the color adjusted JavaFX image, convert it back to a Swing buffered image and return it.
            SnapshotParameters snapshotParameters = new SnapshotParameters();
            snapshotParameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            return SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(
                    imageView.snapshot(
                            snapshotParameters,
                            null
                    ),
                    null
            );
        });

        Platform.runLater(conversionTask);

        return conversionTask.get();
    }
}
```

*ColorAdjustingSwingAppUsingJavaFX.java*

Test harness:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class ColorAdjustingSwingAppUsingJavaFX {

    private static void initAndShowGUI() {
        try {
            // This method is invoked on Swing thread
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();

            // read the original image from a URL.
            URL url = new URL(
                    IMAGE_LOC
            );
            BufferedImage originalImage   = ImageIO.read(url);

            // use JavaFX to convert the original image to monochrome.
            ColorAdjuster colorAdjuster = new ColorAdjuster();
            BufferedImage monochromeImage = colorAdjuster.adjustColor(
                    originalImage,
                    0, -1, 0, 0
            );

            // add the original image and the converted image to the Swing frame.
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.getContentPane().add(
                    new JLabel(
                            new ImageIcon(originalImage)
                    )
            );
            frame.getContentPane().add(
                    new JLabel(
                            new ImageIcon(monochromeImage)
                    )
            );

            // set a handler to close the application on request.
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    // shutdown the JavaFX runtime.
                    Platform.exit();

                    // exit the application.
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

            // display the Swing frame.
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocation(400, 300);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                ColorAdjustingSwingAppUsingJavaFX::initAndShowGUI
        );
    }


    // icon source: http://www.iconarchive.com/artist/aha-soft.html
    // icon license: Free for non-commercial use, commercial usage: Not allowed
    private static final String IMAGE_LOC =
            "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/aha-soft/desktop-buffet/128/Pizza-icon.png";
}
```

Comment: Now, what I'm really interested in knowing is how this got over the "Toolkit not started" exception I got when I tried using `Platform.runLater`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `BufferedImage` to a `javafx.scene.image.Image`, you can use something like...

```
Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(imagem, null);
```

Then you can apply the `ColorAdjust`...

```
ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
colorAdjust.setContrast(0.1);
colorAdjust.setHue(-0.05);
colorAdjust.setBrightness(0.1);
colorAdjust.setSaturation(0.2);

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
imageView.setFitWidth(image.getWidth());
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
imageView.setEffect(colorAdjust);
```

Then convert it back again...

```
imagem = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(imageView.snapshot(null, null), null);
```

This idea is stolen from [jewelsea / SaveAdjustedImage.java](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2870355).  What I don't know is, if the `ImageView` needs to be realised on the screen first all not...

**Updated**

Just so you are aware, you are crossing two different UI frameworks, like they say in the films, "don't cross the streams!"

JavaFX has a much more tightly controlled set of requirements then Swing does, this is both a good and bad thing.

What you MUST do, is get the JavaFX code to run within it's event thread.  This is more tricky than it sounds (and seems to need to be), for example...

[image]

Original | Color adjustments (taken from the [JavaDocs example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/ColorAdjust.html)) | Monochrome...

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.effect.ColorAdjust;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        try {
            System.out.println("Load image...");
            BufferedImage imagem = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));
            Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(imagem, null);

            ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
            colorAdjust.setHue(0);
            colorAdjust.setSaturation(-1);
            colorAdjust.setBrightness(0);
            colorAdjust.setContrast(0);
//          colorAdjust.setHue(-0.05);
//          colorAdjust.setSaturation(0.2);
//          colorAdjust.setBrightness(0.1);
//          colorAdjust.setContrast(0.1);

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
            imageView.setFitWidth(image.getWidth());
            imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
            imageView.setEffect(colorAdjust);

            System.out.println("Convert and save...");
            imagem = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(imageView.snapshot(null, null), null);
            ImageIO.write(imagem, "png", new File("ColorAdjusted.png"));
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Platform.exit();
        }
    }

}
```

The next thing is trying to work out how you would get this to work as a utility class...

Comment: First of all, I just wish to say a huge thanks to you! But my code isn't working, I've edited my post to show what I tryied.